# AWS IAM: Restrict access for CLI, but not Management Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When applying a permission policy to an IAM User, is it possible to restrict access to the client they are using? Specifically, AWS Management Console vs CLI? (Perhaps using a Resource Condition?)

I want to allow a user to perform an action using the AWS Management Console, but not the CLI.

My current solution is to create two IAM accounts for the user. One w/ programmatic access & the other with username/password, but no account w/ both. Then, tailor permission policies to each. Curious if there is a more elegant solution out there.

Comment: Maybe write conditions on the user agent, for example: {"StringLike": {"aws:UserAgent": "aws-cli/*"}}

Comment: I believe you can use aws:TokenIssueTime for this purpose, but curious why you'd want different permission for console and CLI.

Comment: @sudo: granting liberal permissions for users that have CLI access opens doors to programmatic errors that can lead to aws resource catastrophes (say, a bug in their command/script). I consider myself an aws expert and even I do not want my CLI account to have Full Access in *any* service. However, if I'm logged into the AWS Management Console, my interaction with services/resources is very point-and-click / UI-driven and Full Access to specific services ends up being quite convenient. It's just a risk avoidance thing to avoid possible resource disasters.

Comment: @sudo: btw, aws:TokenIssueTime is, as docs say: "...only available in requests that are signed using temporary security credentials."

Comment: @JordanArseno Thanks! I'll test it out. In console, all API calls are made by temporary credentials, so thought the condition key can be used since in CLI, I presume you are using permanent access key (e.g. not calling GetSessionToken).

Comment: @sudo - what is result of your testing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that AWS started showing API instructions in little drop-down windows that correspond to the management console action being performed?

Based on this, and the fact the management console is just a wrapper around their internal API calls, I don't think that a resource permission would allow a user to subset permissions based on where the action is performed.

I think the spirit of IAM dictates that those two accounts *should* have different credentials, because, fundamentally, they have a different set of permissions.